# How can I use multiples selects from different tables?

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

I'm trying to do a report with filter in JasperSoft and I have to put in the same code the queries, but they are from different tables.

I have until now:

```
select 
d.tdok typ,
d.nr numer,
d.symbmg symbol,
d.data dataDok,
d.dokumwe dokumWe,
d.datawe datawe,
d.idkntrh idKth,
d.kwotadok kwotadok,
d.kwotavat,
k.nazwa1 nazwa1,
k.nazwa2 nazwa2
from dokum0 d
join kontrahent0 k on d.idkntrh=k.idkntrh
```

and I want to put:

```
select t.kwota_n kwota_n
from dokumterm t 
where t.dokum_id = id_dokum;

select p.id_pozdok0 AS settledCount
from pozdok p 
where p.dokum_id = id_dokum;

select p.id_pozdok0 AS posCount
from pozdok p 
where p.dokum_id=id_dokum;

select t.kupspr kupspr
from sltdok t
where t.tdok=tdok;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Show us the results from all those queries, and how they're supposed to be combined.

Comment: your question is not clear,please look here to know how to frame a good question  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: is there any relation between tables to combine?

Comment: I will add a filter expression after this code for generation of reports, so I can choose which parameters i will want to generate my report. They are not combineds.

Comment: That is not relation between the tables

Comment: i dont wanna a combination between the tables, just the queries os these differents tables

Comment: Please, add a table of what result you want out of it. Your question is not clear on what kind of combination you want.

Comment: Are you looking for `UNION ALL`?